# Inserting multiple rows into database using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code which inserts 1 row into the database:

```
public function fixed($fieldDay, $fieldNight) {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO tblfixedfare (SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay' FROM tblfixedfare)";

try {
        // Query
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($this->sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        echo $count.' row(s) inserted by SQL: '.$stmt->queryString;

        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        echo 'Error: ' .$pe->getMessage(). 'SQL: '.$stmt->queryString;
        die();
    }

    // Close connection
    $dbh = null;
}

}
```

At the same time this is being executed, I want to insert another row into the same table:

`$this->sql = "INSERT INTO tblfixedfare (SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '$fieldNight' FROM tblfixedfare)";`

How would I go about doing this?

**EDIT**

Also, for both inserts the value for `MAX(FixedFareID)+1` needs to be the same value.

Comment: why don't you just use Auto_increment?

Comment: Just [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) the two `SELECT` statements.

Comment: You're using prepared statements, but you're not binding any parameters, at the same time you're passing raw variables to the queries? Kinda pointless, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the SQL query definition to this:

```
$this->sql = "
    INSERT INTO tblfixedfare 
        SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID) + 1, '1', :fieldDay
        FROM tblfixedfare
        UNION
        SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID) + 1, '2', :fieldNight
        FROM tblfixedfare
";
```

...and change the `execute()` call to this:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
    'fieldDay' => $fieldDay,
    'fieldNight' => $fieldNight
));
```

Comment: Say for example `MAX(FixedFareID)+1` = 5, would that use value 5 for both inserts?

Comment: @nsilva Yes. What else would you expect?

Comment: I've just tried this and I get the following: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '100' FROM tblfixedfare),
               ' at line 2SQL: INSERT INTO tblfixedfare VALUES
                     (SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '100' FROM tblfixedfare),
                     (SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '200' FROM tblfixedfare)

Comment: @nsilva Oh right yes actually you can't do this, duh. Try `INSERT INTO tblfixedfare (SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay' FROM tblfixedfare UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '$fieldNight' FROM tblfixedfare)` - although also note that N.B.'s comment on the question is valid, there is no point in preparing the statement if you just drop raw variables into the query string - use placeholders instead.

Comment: i'm @ work right now but why on earth would that give an error since it's documented in the mySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Is it a special trick for php ?

Comment: Another error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '222' FROM tblfixedfare)' at line 3SQL: INSERT INTO tblfixedfare
                        (SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '111' FROM tblfixedfare
                         UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '222' FROM tblfixedfare)

Comment: @QuadroQ It's the `VALUES` it doesn't like. If you do `INSERT ... SELECT` you don't use the `VALUES (...), (...)` syntax - look very carefully at the syntax definition.

Comment: @nsilva Yeh that was wrong as well. I'm not doing well here am I? Try it without the parens: `INSERT INTO tblfixedfare SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay' FROM tblfixedfare UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '$fieldNight' FROM tblfixedfare` - that really should work, I've done it many time before.

Comment: it's just now i get what he's actually trying to add ! :) Yes, VALUES is no good here and DaveRandom's sintax should work. If it's not ... is jus a matter of ((select) union (select2)) ...

Comment: @QuadroQ Edited, also changed in a way that there is some point in using a prepared statement.